# How to disable response parsing in Karate?

Tags: json, karate

I'm using Karate 0.9.5. and am testing an endpoint that returns a 125MB json response (I know, shouldn't do that over json -- but am stuck for now). How can I disable Karate from parsing the response json and just treat it as plain text? The response takes milliseconds to come over the wire, but Karate just hangs trying to parse the response. I don't need to validate the response, just check for 200 OK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. I suggest you write a Java util (should be just 5-10 lines of code) to do a `GET` or whatever to this end-point and call it from Karate and save to something like `target/temp.json` or discard the response.

Refer to Java interop: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

If you use `karate-apache` then the Apache HTTP Client will be in the classpath. So you can refer to the docs: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e49

Also look at the end of this test for an alternative example of making a GET / POST in Java: [`ProxyServerTest.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-netty/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/ProxyServerTest.java)

Comment: Thanks. I found that disabling DEBUG logging (changed to INFO) brings things under control and testing can proceed.

Comment: @Naeem I just made changes to the "report verbosity" config so that karate will not even try to log the HTTP traffic when switched off, so you can do this even per request or `Scenario`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#report-verbosity - would be great if you can test this, there is a developer-guide in the GitHub wiki